# Using datanucleus-rest with HBASE

Tags: java, hbase, datanucleus

I am trying to get the [datanucleus REST service](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/rest/api.html) (2.0.1) running with [HBASE](http://hbase.apache.org/) (0.90.2).

When accessing the servlet (registering works) however, I am getting a 503:

> HTTP ERROR 503
>
> Problem accessing /dn/. Reason:
>
> ```
> org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: There is no
> available StoreManager of type "rdbms". Make sure that you have put
> the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if
> defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide
> persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
> ```

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="test">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory</provider>
    <class>com.bla.MyClass</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes />
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.storeManagerType" value="hbase" />
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="hbase" />
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionUserName" value="" />
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionPassword" value="" />
        <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateTables" value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateColumns" value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.Multithreaded" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I am unsure however with the values for

- provider
- datanucleus.storeManagerType

Can anyone give me a hint where I might be wrong or point me to some documentation about this?

Comment: especially the value of <provider> seems to be "org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl" in all of the examples.

Comment: Provider must be: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl and datanucleus.storeManagerType is not needed. Also don't forget to make the persistence-unit name-Attribute the same as the one specified in the web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provider is irrelevant since the backend uses JDO; persistence.xml is simply to define the connection, properties (and classes if required).

datanucleus.storeManagerType is irrelevant too, since that is only when you specify the connection using JNDI, as per what the docs say clearly.

So you don't have datanucleus-hbase, and one of the dependent jars in your classpath.

Obviously looking at the log may help. I can use DataNucleus v3 REST with HBase no problem at all